# Watin causes high CPU usage

Tags: c#, watin, cpu-usage

I'm using Watin like so:

```
private IE myie;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myie = new IE();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }

    myie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
    myie.WaitForComplete();

}
```

The problem is, however, once browser window is opened - my C# app starts to consume CPU.
According to task manager - in IDLE state my program consumes from 7% to 20% CPU power. (I have AMD 2core 5000+)

Once you close the IE instance (window) - CPU usage problem disappears, so the problem lies somewhere within Watin.

Who do I fix it? What causes CPU drain?

Here, proof:

[image]

**Project:** [download on skydrive](http://sdrv.ms/1232yeS)

Can anybody confirm the bug? Or maybe it's just my PC fails at some point

Comment: new IE window instance. More info here: http://watin.org/

Comment: I am curious, what else do you have running along with this project?  I have been using WatiN for years and haven't had this issue.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I don't understand what you mean by this! @Brian nothing! Only this one project. One simple line of code causes CPU drain: `IE myie = new IE("http://www.google.com");` on my PC!! I have tried changing Framework to 3.5 instead of 4, tried to change Bits (x64, x86), tried to tick "optimization", "unsafe code".. nothing is helping..

Comment: Are you sure it's not IE itself causing the drain? Try opening something less stressful, like notepad.

Comment: manually opened IE (running aside from my program) doesn't drain CPU, nor does Notepad or any other program running on my PC (livemail, skydrive, chrome, explorer, adobe, skype, etc..).

Comment: please check the image (I've edited my post). If anybody is interested - i can upload the project and post a download link.. ok, here: http://sdrv.ms/1232yeS

Comment: Can somebody confirm if the bug exists or is it just me?

Comment: Its just you. Confirmed.

Comment: damn.. I'm not making this up ;( Most likely some program is interfering with Watin instance. I'll restart my PC later and check if CPU drain is there.. thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind - and I am sure you know this already - WatiN is open-source so, there will be bugs in it.  Like you, I get a spike of CPU usage when launching the form in *both IE and Firefox*; but returns to normal in a pretty short order.  My advice to you would be to reach out to [the WatiN Team](http://watin.org/team/).  I have posted my code below as well:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using WatiN.Core;

    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               IE testIE = new IE("http://www.google.com");
               //FireFox testFF = new FireFox("http://www.google.com");
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: in my case usage never returns to normal.. anyway, I'll test the app on cold-boot after PC restart later.